# CTRL + C for copy paste if something is marked AND interrupting commands

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys

Title is already the question. I bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, sadly this deactivates interrupting commands. I'm trying to let the shell also interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (JetBrains IDEs Terminals do this and others too)

Is this possible to achieve in the gnome shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> both acting as a shortcut to copy, and act as the interrupt symbol for terminal commands. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy a highlighted section from the terminal instead.

Comment: Why not? The terminal integrated into JetBrains can do it.

Comment: Well, it is not possible in Gnome Shell, more specifically the gnome-terminal emulator that it uses. Why, that is probably how it is set up and intercepts keys.

Comment: Pretty sure it is possible. Had a terminal on mint linux (based on Ubuntu iirc) which did that. I think its name was something like "Beautiful Terminal" or something